# 'invalid command' error in expect script that is fine in interactive mode

Tags: linux, shell

I have a problem in running an expect script (very new in this).
Here is what I have now in an expect script `autorun.exp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
cd /auto/rmscr/shared_resources/qiuyuguo/softwares/QuEST_2.4
./generate_QuEST_parameters.pl -sam_align_ChIP A.sam -sam_align_RX_noIP \
    B.sam -rp mm10_bychr -ap ./output_directory -ChIP_name name
```

After running this script, what I got is this:

```
[qiuyuguo@hpc-uec 20150605]$ ./auto_run.exp
invalid command name "./generate_QuEST_parameters.pl"
    while executing
"./generate_QuEST_parameters.pl -sam_align_ChIP A.sam -s..."
    (file "./auto_run.exp" line 3)
```

Interestingly, the content in the script runs fine in the interactive mode of expect. Could I get a hint about what is going on?

Comment: You can edit your post to make it correct.

Comment: The purpose of this script is to auto run a script that requires inputing parameters in the middle of the program running. Would also be helpful if theres an easier alternative to do so.

Comment: Your script does not look like an `Expect` script. Try running it with `sh auto_run.exp`.

Answer (score 0):

expect script should have a `spawn` command, a `expect` command and a `send` command.

This is a example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn su -l test
expect "Password: " {
  send "xxxxx\r"
}
expect "# " {
  send "exit\r"
}
expect eof {
  exit
}
```